# Retrieving the audio leftPeak and rightPeak from a Video Netstream?

Tags: actionscript-3

*I think my problem is clear. How to retrieve the audio leftPeak and rightPeak from a Video Netstream? I attached leftPeak and rightPeak property to my netstream object but it did not work.*

Comment: Are you asking how to scan a video file and retrieve it's loudest point?  I'm not sure what you mean by attached leftPeak and rightPeak property to your netstream.  netStream doesn't have a leftPeak or rightPeak property.

Comment: Hi.That's exactly what I want. netStream doesn't have a leftPeak or rightPeak property. I previously used leftPeak and rightPeak property to animate mask equalizer for a flash AS3 mp3 player, But sound channel doesn't work with flv.